# How to track down a Night Creature in a city?

Tags: dwarf-fortress-adventure

Several times in adventure mode, I've been given missions to hunt down a vampire (usually with a ridiculous kill total) hiding in a city, with nothing but a name to go on. The quest tracker only points me to an area of the city (and sometimes a point just outside the city itself).

Is there any way to quickly and easily find the vampire without having to talk to every single citizen in the city and ask their name (and then accuse them of being a night creature)?

Comment: Sometimes the night creatures can live in the sewers under cities. If that is so. Good luck. Sucks, but sometimes it can take forever to find them.

Comment: @Samthere The general game tag was deliberately removed a while ago, so it doesn't need to be added back.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Was going for consistency - all but 2 questions with the dwarf-fortress-adventure tag are also tagged with dwarf-fortress, and it seems like people following the dwarf-fortress tag  would want the adventure results. I'd think it should be both, unless dwarf-fortress-adventure could be made to imply the dwarf-fortress tag.

Comment: @Samthere People who want to follow both can do so by choice with [dwarf-fortress*]. Tagging them all together makes that useless, and means people who only follow one get the other mixed in even if they don't want it.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Well, the same is true for any game. For example, every question with the "tf2-pyro" tag also has "team-fortress-2", and that doesn't make it useless. Every question about a game has the tag for that specific game, except apparently 2 questions about a certain part of DF. Someone looking at tags and seeing "Dwarf Fortress" won't think "oh, I should go find the separate tag for half of that game as well", nor should users be expected to use wildcard searches to subscribe to one game. Why not a fortress tag as well? Adventure tag is a good thing, but not on its own.

Comment: @Samthere Perhaps you'd like to open a Meta question about it? That would get the wider community's view in one place—debating with just me isn't useful on its own. (And editing this Q yet again to change the tags would put it into edit war territory, which we should avoid.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDied Finally got round to it! :P Link is here http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7148/using-game-sub-tags-but-not-using-the-game-tag

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you offer service to the people of the city where the creature hides, and the quest they're offering you is to hunt down that particular creature, they'll guide you (for example, saying that the creature hides in a leatherworking shop to the South).

A good place to look is in the official buildings - vampires often ascend to important ranks. Vampires with lots of kills might also wear a lot of jewellery made from their victims.

Other than that, there's no simple way.

Answer (score 1):

DFHack have command [cursecheck](https://github.com/peterix/dfhack#cursecheck) to check for cursed creatures (ghosts, vampires, necromancers, werebeasts, zombies). You can check creature under cursor, it will save fome time from talking to every person.

Comment: does DFHack work in adventure mode? I thought that was only Fortress mode too.

Comment: Yes, it should work, it have commands dedicated for adventurer mode.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "**No**", there is not a quickly and easy way to find them.

Your only legit bet is to walk around and randomly accuse people.